# C++ Vector keyword "ref"

Tags: c++, vector

I woud like to know what is the meanig of "ref" in a vector type definition.

I am new to C++ and on the piece of code I am stripping out to learn I found

```
vector<ref<StupidBug> > bugs;
```

where “StupidBug” is a class.

It doesn't compile in gcc/C++11 because "template argument ">" is invalid" but moving the “>” to the left, closer to the previous one still gives the same error

That confuses me and I don't know anymore where is the mistake.

The code is a few years old, could it be bad writing? Does "ref" belong to c++?

Is that a multivector? or a template?

The  background info:

The whole is about inserting  and moving "bugs" in grid and the vector holds the number of bugs and put them in a certain position.

Here the code, first I have a Stupidbug class

```
class StupidBug
{

public:
  int x();
  int y();

  // member initialization list
  StupidBug(GraphID_t i=-1): cellID(i) {}

  void move();
  void draw(const eco_string& canvas);
};
```

And the vector with the "ref" is in another class:

```
class Model: public Space
{

public:
urand u;     //random generator for positions
int tstep;   //timestep - updated each time moveBugs is called
int scale;   //no. pixels used to represent bugs
vector<ref<StupidBug> > bugs;
 addBugs(int nBugs);
void addBugs();
void moveBugs();
void draw(TCL_args args);
};
```

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: It isn't a keyword. It is the name of a function template.

Comment: As per @StoryTeller s comment below, you might be looking for std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<StupidBug>>

Comment: @EJP You are totally wrong. It si a user-defined smart pointer.

Comment: You said it's from 2006, is your project built with boost by any chance?

Comment: @StoryTeller, it doesn't use boost. It is using a series of custom libraries which where updated without updating the code of the program. In the updated libraries I have a ref.h with template<class T >
void  std::swap (classdesc::ref< T > &x, classdesc::ref< T > &y)

Answer (score 7):

Yet another reason to stop `using namespace std;`

It's the function template [`std::ref<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)

`vector<ref<StupidBug> >` can't be compiled because `std::vector` expect a type (in fact 2 type but the other is defaulted) and you provided a function `std::ref<StupidBug>`

---

It's probably that your old project have another `ref` template and somehow, when compile with C++11, it choose `std::ref` instead of that template.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure that it is a user-defined class similar to smart pointers that was designed to substitute standard class `std::auto_ptr` that can not be used with the class `std::vector`.

It is possible that this class uses a reference count of objects.

Now instead of

```
vector<ref<StupidBug> > bugs;
```

you can write for example

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<StupidBug> > bugs;
```

Pay attention to this record of two '>" symbols

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<StupidBug> > bugs;
                               ^^^^
```

It means that the code was compiled according to the C++ 2003 Standard when there were not new smart pointers except `std::auto_ptr` that can not be used with vectors.

There was a problem in the old C++ Standard relative to `std::auto_ptr`. As result new smart pointers were introduced in the new C++ Standard like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` that can be used along with `std::vector` and other standard containers.

This class was used because the code is old and the new Standard was not yet adopted with its new classes or maybe it has functionality that is absent in the Standard or more suitable for some class of tasks.

At  that time for example Scott Meyers in his book `More Effective C++` was showing how a smart pointer with a reference count can be written. This theme wss popular at that days of the C++ 2003 Standard.:)

It is evident that this has nothing common with the standard function `std::ref` that also was introduced in the C++ 2011 except its name.:)

When the code was written there was neither standard function `std::ref`.:)

Just look through the header where the class is defined.:)

Now according to the C++ Standard (D.10 auto_ptr)

> The class template auto_ptr is deprecated. [ Note: The class template
>   unique_ptr (20.7.1) provides a better solution. —end note ]

Thus due to the new smart pointers introduced in the new C++ Standard it seems there is no need any more to use this user-defined class ref.

Comment: Too many assumptions that lead to wrong conclusions about code that isn't seen. It's quite evident from the error message that this is an attempt to misuse `std::ref` instead of `std::reference_wrapper`

Comment: @StoryTeller You are entirely wrong. It is a user-defined class. The problem is that the required header is not included and nothing more.:)

Comment: No, that's what you (erroneously) assume happens. There is nothing in the question itself to suggest it.  Trying a [simple example in gcc](http://ideone.com/TwA80b) produces the exact error the OP is getting *"error: template argument 2 is invalid"*

Comment: @StoryTeller See one more my answer.:)

Comment: You just followed your assumptions some more, so it doesn't really change my opinion... Nothing you said about smart pointers is wrong, it's just irrelevant to what we have here.

Comment: @StoryTeller What I wrote is correct. I remember I myself used such a  class with vectors and moreover it also was named ref. :)

Comment: @StoryTeller It is funny that a correct answer is down-voted but a wrong answer is up-voted 6 times. Thank you.:)

Comment: For your information the original code is from 2006

Comment: @JoselitoS It confirms that I am right. At that time the C++ 2003 Standard with minor changes in 2005 was active. auto_ptr can not be used with std::vector. So programmers used their own smart pointers. The next C++ Standard appeared only in 2011 year. And even after that most compilers did not support all the features of the C++ 2011 Standard.

Comment: @JoselitoS As for other answer then there is written a nonsence. The name ref used in your example has nothing common with the standard function std::ref introduced in the C++ 2011 Standard.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to your answers I was able to fix the issue.

Actually the code is from 2006 and used the c++03 Standard

```
ref<StupidBug>
```

is a template used as a custom smart pointer with some extra fuctions and not the „std::ref“ function. It is defined in a header called „classdesc“

For some reason even if I am not using "using namespace std;"  the compiler whats to use the „ref“ function instead of the template.

The workaround for me has been using

```
classdesc::ref<StupidBug>
```

being „classdesc“ where the original template lives.

Using the new samart pointers from C++11 ( shared_ptr ) didn't work either because of the extra functions of the original template.

I don't know who was more right if @Vlad from Moscow or @StoryTeller....